# Generate UPDATE statements on top of a SELECT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called EMPLOYEE with ID column as my Primary Key in an Oracle database

```
ID   FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
 1      ABC       DEF
 2      IJK       LMN
 3      OPQ       RST
 4      UVW       XYZ
 5      GBC       GEF
 6      IBC       JEF
 7      KBC       LEF
 8      MBC       NEF`
```

Now I run a SELECT statement with a filter like—

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID >3;
```

Output:

```
FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
  UVW          XYZ
  GBC          GEF
  IBC          JEF
  KBC          LEF
  MBC          NEF
```

I am trying build UPDATE statements based of the the SELECT statement above. For example, I am trying to generate UPDATES like below, so that I can run on another database (instead of using Datapump)

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=‘UVW’, LAST_NAME=‘XYZ’ WHERE ID=4;
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=‘GBC’, LAST_NAME=‘GEF’ WHERE ID=5;
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=‘IBC’, LAST_NAME=‘JEF’ WHERE ID=6;
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=‘KBC’, LAST_NAME=‘LEF’ WHERE ID=7;
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=‘MBC’, LAST_NAME=‘NEF’ WHERE ID=8;
```

I have tried using concatenation operator, but could not do it successfully. Could you please suggest what would be the right way to generate the above UPDATE statements for respective ID column value based on the filter condition (in this case ID>3)

Appreciate your help with this one.

I have tried something like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    (SELECT 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=' ||FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID>3),
    ', ',
    (SELECT ', LAST_NAME=' ||LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID>3),
    ', ',
    (SELECT 'WHERE ID=' ||ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID>3)
) AS concatenated_output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were running head-long into some deep code *"Inception"*.

Instead, it might help to think of each returned record as its own UPDATE statement string:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME=''' || FIRST_NAME || ''', LAST_NAME=''' || LAST_NAME || ''' WHERE ID=' || ID || ';' as update_statement
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID>3
```

For clarification, the double single-quotes just mean a single single-quote when used inside of a string. As an example: `SELECT ''''` if you run it by itself will return `'`.

This should spit out a row for each UPDATE statement that you can copy/paste into your other system. It's not the most effective ETL, but for small data, it will do the job.